# Could someone make this figure, but with homoskedasticity?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The amazing, elegant graph below is from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254484/how-to-make-a-graph-of-heteroskedasticity-with-tikz-pgf/254494). Could someone help me make this same graph, but with homoskedasticity (instead of heteroskedasticity)?  Perhaps [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake)? Thank you, Jake, for the original.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Could you please add a minimal working example?

Comment: You want the width of the Gaussians to remain constant? If so, this is a simple change of Jake's great answer. The third argument of his functions is the width, you only need to take it equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity) you seem to want Gaussians whose width doesn't change when you are asking about  homoskedasticity. And this can be achieved with a minimal surgery of [Jake's great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254494/121799).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{dot}
{%
    \fill circle [x radius=0.02, y radius=0.08];
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ % Define Normal Probability Function
declare function={
            normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        },
    declare function={invgauss(\a,\b) = sqrt(-2*ln(\a))*cos(deg(2*pi*\b));}
       ]
\begin{axis}[
    %no markers,
    domain=0:12,
    zmin=0, zmax=1,
    xmin=0, xmax=3,
    samples=200,
   samples y=0,
    view={40}{30},
    axis lines=middle,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    xtick={0.5,1.5,2.5},
    xmajorgrids,
    xticklabels={},
    ytick=\empty,
    xticklabels={$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$},
    ztick=\empty,
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0,0)}, anchor=west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1,0)}, anchor=south west},
    zlabel=Probability density, zlabel style={at={(rel axis cs:0,0,0.5)}, rotate=90, anchor=south},
    set layers, mark=cube
  ]

\addplot3 [gray!50, only marks, mark=dot, mark layer=like plot, samples=200,
domain=0.1:2.9, on layer=axis background] (x, {1.5*(x-0.5)+3+invgauss(rnd,rnd)}, 0);
\addplot3 [samples=2, samples y=0, domain=0:3] (x, {1.5*(x-0.5)+3}, 0);
\addplot3 [cyan!50!black, thick] (0.5, x, {normal(x, 3, 0.75)});
\addplot3 [cyan!50!black, thick] (1.5, x, {normal(x, 4.5, 0.75)});
\addplot3 [cyan!50!black, thick] (2.5, x, {normal(x, 6, 0.75)});

\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
\draw [gray, on layer=axis background] (0.5, 3, 0) -- (0.5, 3, {normal(0,0,0.75)}) (0.5,0,0) -- (0.5,12,0)
    (1.5, 4.5, 0) -- (1.5, 4.5, {normal(0,0,0.7)}) (1.5,0,0) -- (1.5,12,0)
    (2.5, 6, 0) -- (2.5, 6, {normal(0,0,0.75)}) (2.5,0,0) -- (2.5,12,0);

\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated! I knew it would be easy for the right person.