# How to plot asymptomatic curve and draw a bell curve on different points

Tags: pgfplots

[image: hypothetical relation]
I am writing my thesis and i have draw a hypothetical curve. Later I have to relate this with simulated data. The picture has a quadratic equation and some sample points are drawn. Now i have to draw a bell curve on each data points to show that their mean lies on the curve or they stay within the deviation. How do I draw that? Is it even possible to draw something like this. I am sorry, i already left the lab and couldn't bring the code related to the picture. Any help or guidance is really appreciated. Please also let me know if the question is not clear. I am also stumbling on making my expectation clear. Thanks in advance. 
[image: edited picture]

Hope this sheds some light.

Comment: Hi tt_pre, welcome to the site! Do you have something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125634/plotting-population-regression-function-with-pgfplot/125635#125635 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254494/2552 in mind? Could you maybe try to clarify the result you're trying to get, by drawing a picture by hand and including it in your question?

Comment: Hi i have to try out the links you posted. In the meantime i draw by hand on mobile. Worst picture ever.